# Do any items break down/refine into cooking materials?

Tags: guild-wars-2

Armor and scrap items break down into ore, is there an equivalent for cooking materials?  Or are they only obtained through gathering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have encountered playing through the game, they can only be found through gathering.

I am currently level 80 and have been in all the zones including the WvW ones. I have not seen an alternative source of cooking mats yet. My guild mates agree with my and a quick google search does not turn up anything on the contrary.

Comment: As of the 9/7 patch, cooking materials also can drop from bags (i.e., from bandits). These were the same cooking materials that were removed from karma vendors.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Eh? Are they rarer than the usual loot like the vials of blood and claws? I don't remember getting any cooking stuff from the bags the past 2 days, although i have not been farming much recently.

Comment: I was farming bandits yesterday and I got 25 sticks of butter and an apple out of it. This made me sad because I was looking for jute scraps :(

Comment: @TerryChia It may just be the "Bag of Stolen Supplies". Bandits love butter.

Comment: @Tacroy Yeah, i noticed loads of sticks of butter from the bags recently. Annoys the hell out of me because i don't need butter i need jute :p

Comment: Cinnamon can be acquired from harvesting the Tier 1 trees, Walnuts from Tier 2.